# RF module with noisy supply

Tags: rf, 433mhz

- Brief description of the context (not really necessary to answer):

I built a quadcopter. The motors (small DC motors) and the electronics are powered by a single 3.7-4.2v battery. To prevent the microcontroller and the sensor to reset when there is a current spike in the motor's circuit, I put a 1000uF capacitor near the electronic part's supply and a schottky diode between the battery "+" and the capacitor, so that only the electronic circuit can use the capacitor's charge when needed. I also built a simple remote control which communicates with the quadcopter trough a couple of cheap 433mHz rf modules (on the receiver stands "xy-mk-5v").
At this very moment I can send all the needed settings to the quadcopter, calibrate it to remain as steady as possible and eventually tell him to fly: it takes off and flies for 3 seconds, then it automatically shuts down (as I wrote in the code for safety reasons). But during the flight there's a lot of noise in the circuit and the quadcopter can't receive any rf message (so I can't control it).

---

- The question:

What I need now is a rf sistem which works with a noisy supply. I think I could:

a) filter the power supply;

b) change the rf modules (I payed something like 2 USD for the actual ones, but I could spend 20-30 $);

c) change the antennas (now I use a 172mm wires)

Would these things help? What else could I do? And how could I do these things (how could I build a good filter? What shape should the antennas have?)

Comment: You should describe the noise so we can tell more

Comment: Just to understand your problem. Some questions:
1. Is your circuit on PCB. If so is there ground polygons, small ceramic filtering/coupling capacitors?
2. Do you use any coding scheme for rf communication?
3. Could you post any photo?

Comment: Are you sure you can actually use 433 MHz? Depending on local regulations this may not be an appropriate choice. And should you go for another frequency (e.g. 2.4 GHz) your noise problems could disappear and/or require a different fix.

Comment: While sometimes difficult, attacking the noise *source* often provides a better result than attacking the noise's nasty effect on other modules. Start there first - perhaps you can use the RF comms to indicate success of your noise-suppressing efforts.

Comment: @tibo yes, I can. But since I'm probably buying new modules I could also change (2.4ghz ks allowed too). If I change what would the main differences be (regarding the noise problem)?

Comment: @glen_geek I put a 0.1uF cap between each motor's terminals, but there is still too much noise. What could I do more? Would a cap from each terminal to the motor's case be useful?

Comment: @PlasmaHH That's my biggest difficulty in resolving this problem: I don't have any oscilloscope, and I'll not be able to have one whitin the next weeks, but I would like to find at least a temporary solution before that

Comment: No one uses those 433 mhz modules for aircraft, use 2.4 ghz ones.  If you had spent a fraction of the time you have been asking questions here reading about how these aircraft *actually* work on a place like rcgroups you would be in far better shape.  Additionally most of the responses you get here are guesses from first principles backed by no actual experience of your problem.  Unsurprisingly, many are wrong.

Comment: @ChrisStratton 433MHz would allow you to fly behind obstacles with a far lesser chance of losing radio connection, compared with 2.4GHz. Overall, 433MHz is far more rugged. Though of course for only $2 you will just get crap.

Comment: @Lundin - not really. The radio problem is that the 433 MHz *modules* being used are horrible compared to the *usual* 2.4 GHz ones, underperforming even in the absence of noise or obstacles.  A well implemented radio link will recover when the aircraft returns to the pilot's (and thus radio's) view.  If it is going to be intentionally operated out of sight, a completely different scheme is needed - not *flight* commands, but rather mission commands to a far more sophisticated autopilot.  The main problem is that the poster is not utilizing published knowledge of the issues and known solutions.

Comment: At what voltage are the RF modules being powered?  Are you powering them directly from the battery/capacitor you describe in the question?

Comment: @denver meanwhile I changed the RF modules. I’m now using a couple of RFM69HCW modules, and they show much less noise-related problems. But my first and third questions still remain.

Answer (score 2):

I'm not sure what range you are looking for, but for 433Mhz I have been successful using the antenna as described in the datasheet for the [WL101 and WL102](https://www.aliexpress.com/item/433mhz-rf-Transmitter-and-Receiver-superheterodyne-UHF-ASK-remote-control-Module-with-Antenna-Kit-small-size/32651427149.html?spm=2114.search0104.3.1.1h3VXe&ws_ab_test=searchweb0_0,searchweb201602_4_10152_10065_10151_10344_10068_10130_10345_10324_10342_10547_10325_10343_10546_10340_10341_10548_5690020_10545_10541_10562_10084_10083_10307_10539_5080015_10312_10059_10313_10314_10534_10533_100031_10604_10603_10103_10594_10557_10558_10596_10595_10142_10107,searchweb201603_12,ppcSwitch_5&algo_expid=264f1ece-c2f3-40fd-9d5b-9c09147c7c12-0&algo_pvid=264f1ece-c2f3-40fd-9d5b-9c09147c7c12&rmStoreLevelAB=3) modules.

26 turns of 3mm diameter with a 12mm tail for connecting to the module.
For this I use an insulated 22 gauge wire and wrap it around the copper ground wire taken from household wiring.  The result has been compact and worked for me.

[image]

[image]